# Microsoft Exchange – get all mail traffic senders and receivers

Tags: exchange-server

I'm in a process of creating security software that will address a specific type of security problem. In order to do that I would need to gather information about all the mails that are sent using Microsoft exchange. The information needed is mail's sender, receivers and timestamp. Actually I don’t even need to hold the information on real-time just counters for each sender-receiver pair for specific time frame.
How can I do that?
Is there some Exchange's service that I can use to get this information?
Must such a component be installed on each exchange server (hub, mailbox server etc')?
Are there Exchange's logs or internal database that hold such information?

Comment: Hi did you find any answer to your question.